# "Аргумент" с каким предлогом?

Tags: стилистика

Филологи,помогите! Возможно ли сочетание существительного "аргумент" с предлогом "для" не только в разговорной речи,но и в научных статьях,например? Оправдано ли использование предлога в предложении:"Вторым аргументом для охраны этой местности..."

Comment: Гейзеры — это природное явление; а глазами и в устах человека, оценивающего их с какой-то позиции, — факторы, характеризующие местность. Но не аргументы! В образной устной речи, призванной воздействовать на чувства слушающих, да и в публицистике, допустимо, конечно, многое. Но в научной... вряд ли. Это помимо вопроса об уместности конкретного предлога.


Answer (score 1):

Смысл не схватывается наверняка, но здесь, судя по всему, должно быть "в пользу охраны".
А еще лучше - не аргументом, а доводом"

Comment: Спасибо."В пользу"-это понятно,что наилучший вариант. Дело в том,что  при переводе,я написала именно предлог "для",является ли это грубой ошибкой?"Вторым аргументом для охраны этой местности были Гейзеры, открытые гидрологом..."

Comment: Шут его знает, насколько серьезна эта ощибка. Но слух немного режет.
Я бы точно воздержался от этого "для", в аглийском он имеет гораздо больше функций.

Answer (score 1):

Если это экзамен по лингвистике,думаю, отметят как лексическую ошибку - это лексическая несочетаемость.Аргумент (довод, основание, приводимые в доказательство чего-л.) может быть для доказательства мысли о необходимости охраны, а не для самой охраны.Вот "в пользу" было бы действительно в самый раз. В научном тексте явная ошибка, в устной речи, склонной к упрощению и пропускам слов, вполне допустимо.

Comment: Людмила, это не экзамен, это перевод...

Comment: Тогда решающим будет человеческий фактор. Когда проверяют ученическое сочинение, например,за одно и то же сочинение можно получить и "5", и "3".Это вполне объяснимо влиянием психологических факторов и характером проверяющего.